# Full text search in webform

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform, drupal-search

I have created a form using webform and used in view to display filled entries. now i want to make full text search which can search data from available data in webforms. I have tried to index webforms field but there is no webform type in index type in search Api. please help how i can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps..

1. Structure ->datatables->webform tables set sid as Primary key.
2. Configure Search check all the fields.
3. Clear cache
4. Crate new search index
5. Select webform fields and indexed all.
6. Create new view from indexed Search.
7. Select Full text search from search fields